# Defining a Medication Schedule in FHIR DSTU2

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

We are looking to define a Medication Schedule using the FHIR Medicatation Prescription resource.  Data model aside the schedule is as follows:

- Drug / Medication
- Start Date
- End Date
- Administration times
- Site / Route

For example

> Amoxicillin 50mg - Orally - From 01/06/2015 to 05/06/2015 3 times a
>   day : 09.00 / 13.00 / 18.00

Does anybody know if this is possible with the existing DSTU2 specification?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Yes, this is possible.</strike>
This is possible but only in a laborious way.

You want this to be a [MedicationPrescription](http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May/medicationprescription.html). Ideally this would be a `dosageInstruction.dosageTiming` [Timing](http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May/datatypes.html#Timing) property, but this element can not (yet?) specify specific `Time`s during a day. You will have to create one `dosageInstruction.scheduledDateTime` for every occurrence of your prescription.

Comment: We have looked at dosage instruction however it does not seem to be possible to define specific times for drug administrator.  3 times a days is possible but not 3 times a day at 13.000, 17.00 and 21.00

Comment: @MrEyes You can repeat `dosageInstruction` and set its `scheduledDateTime`. Or you can go crazy with the [_Timing_](http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May/datatypes.html#Timing) element.

Comment: Would you envisage specifying a dosage instruction for each timed event, or would you specify all the datetimes in the MedicationPrescription.dosageInstruction.scheduledTiming.event array

Comment: It would be preferable to use _Timing_ for this, but I also don't see how you can use fixed times of the day with it (maybe @lmckenzi can help). I was about to suggest that yes, you create one `dosageInstruction.scheduledDateTime` for every occurrence, when I realized this prescription is for 5 months, not 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

The Timing data type is intended to support this.  It allows you to say "3 times per day" and also enumerate the specific times.

Comment: you mean enumerate all `DateTime`s for the whole duration, or is it possible to specify just the three `Time`s, to be repeated every day?

Comment: The latter isn't possible with that structure.  Someone's requested an extension to capture offsets, but that's not quite the same.  Suggest submitting a change request.

Answer (score 0):

This object is now [MedicationOrder](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medicationorder.html)

Please see answers / comments here:

[MedicationOrder for Times of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638744/medicationorder-for-times-of-day/40656457#40656457)

This is hopefully coming soon